# How can I define a shared persistent volume between two different deployments in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-storage, kubernetes-pvc

I'm trying to define a shared persistent volume in k8s between two different deployments, and I've encountered some issues:

I have 2 pods for each deployment and between the deployments I'm trying to configure a shared volume - that mean that if I create a txt file in deplyment1/pod1 and I take a look in deplyment1/pod2 - I can't see the file.

The second issue is that I can't see the files in another deployment (deplyment2) - what's currently happening is that each pod created its own separated volume instead of sharing the same volume.

My goal, in the end, is to create a shared volume between the pods and the deployments.
It's important to note that I'm running on GKE.

Below are my current configurations

Deployment 1:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: app1
          ports:
            - name: grpc
              containerPort: 11111
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 300m
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test
              mountPath: /etc/test/configs
      volumes:
        - name: test
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-claim
```

Deployment 2:

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: app2
      namespace: test
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: app2
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: app2
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: server
              image: app2
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 22222
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: 300m
                limits:
                  cpu: 500m
              volumeMounts:
                - name: test
                  mountPath: /etc/test/configs
          volumes:
            - name: test
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: my-claim
```

Persistent Volume:

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: test-pv
      namespace: test
    spec:
      capacity:
        storage: 5Gi
      volumeMode: Filesystem
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
      persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
      storageClassName: fast
      local:
        path: /etc/test/configs
      nodeAffinity:
        required:
          nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool
              operator: In
              values:
              - default-pool
```

```yaml
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: my-claim
      namespace: test
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: fast
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
      storageClassName: fast
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

```yaml
    apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
    kind: StorageClass
    metadata:
      name: fast
    provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
    parameters:
      type: pd-ssd
      fstype: ext4
      replication-type: regional-pd
```

and describe pv and pvc:

```sh
     $ kubectl describe pvc -n test
        Name:          my-claim
        Namespace:     test
        StorageClass:  fast
        Status:        Bound
        Volume:        test-pv
        Labels:        <none>
        Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
                       pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
                       volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: fast
        Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
        Capacity:      5Gi
        Access Modes:  RWX
        VolumeMode:    Filesystem
        Mounted By:    <none>
        Events:        <none>
```

```sh
      $ kubectl describe pv -n test
        Name:              test-pv
        Labels:            <none>
        Annotations:       pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
        Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
        StorageClass:      fast
        Status:            Bound
        Claim:             test/my-claim
        Reclaim Policy:    Retain
        Access Modes:      RWX
        VolumeMode:        Filesystem
        Capacity:          5Gi
        Node Affinity:
          Required Terms:
            Term 0:        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool in [default-pool]
        Message:
        Source:
            Type:  LocalVolume (a persistent volume backed by local storage on a node)
            Path:  /etc/test/configs
        Events:    <none>
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. You could setup a container configured with NFS and create exports that the other containers can mount.https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs

Answer (score 1):

GCE-PD CSI storage driver does not support `ReadWriteMany`. You need to use `ReadOnlyMany`. For `ReadWriteMany` you need to use GFS mounts.

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks) on how to use persistent disks with multiple readers

Creating a `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-readonly-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: my-readonly-pvc
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: my-test-disk
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-readonly-pvc
spec:
  # Specify "" as the storageClassName so it matches the PersistentVolume's StorageClass.
  # A nil storageClassName value uses the default StorageClass. For details, see
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1
  storageClassName: ""
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Using the `PersistentVolumeClaim` in a Pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-pvc
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    name: busybox
    command:
      - "sleep"
      - "3600"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-mnt
      name: my-volume
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: my-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: my-readonly-pvc
      readOnly: true
```

Now, you can have multiple Pods on different nodes that can all mount this `PersistentVolumeClaim` in read-only mode. However, you can't attach persistent disks in write mode on multiple nodes at the same time

Comment: when i tried to do this, i encountered with issues.
```
- test:pod/app1-69f499c8d-srff2: 0/9 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 6 node(s) had 
```
volume node affinity conflict.
and this is my problem.
when the pods goes up, the first pods catches the volume and the other pods frome other apps can't connect to volume.
can you explain more about nfs way?